# Few queries on how to set real time clock value in DS1307

Tags: rtc

I need to integrate `DS1307 RTC` in my project. I have somehow managed to write I2C code and interfaced it with PIC32. I need to make a logic so that it shows real time values on `UART`. Now to display it on UART, the values need to be converted into `ASCII`. So lets say if I set `13` to its `seconds` register then I am getting this value in `I2C2RCV register` but on the terminal it is displaying some random ASCII character.

After converting this value to ASCII, I am receiving `51 49` on terminal. I am using below logic for conversion:

```
//i2cbyte : Received values from I2C

char  i2cbyte;
unsigned char x,y,p1,p2;
char value1[10] ;
char value2[10] ;
 x = i2cbyte & 0x0F;
 p1 = x | 0x30;
 y = i2cbyte & 0xF0;
 y = y >> 4;
 p2 = y | 0x30;
 sprintf(value1,"%d",p1);
 sprintf(value2,"%d",p2); 
 putsUART1(value1);
 putsUART1(value2);
```

So I set `13` and I received `51 49`. So what value should I set in my code to get real time value on UART. Is it possible to get values on UART because inside the code I am getting the real time value but to display it outside the code, the values need to be converted which becomes something else. How can I resolve this?

After setting the values in the register of `RTC`, do I need to use some logic to update it. Datasheet tell that registers are automatically updated. But what happens during programming is  I am setting values to registers and then reading it but the values are not updating. I am always receiving what I am writing.
How to set values

Please help.!

CODE:

```
int main(void)
{

OpenUART1( UART_EN | UART_NO_PAR_8BIT | UART_1STOPBIT  , UART_RX_ENABLE | UART_TX_ENABLE, (FPB/16/BAUDRATE)-1 );


I2C2BRG = 0xA3;     //I2C Baudrate
I2CEnable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, TRUE);    //I2C module On

StartTransfer(FALSE);      //I2C Start
TransmitOneByte(0xD0);  //slave address
TransmitOneByte(0x00); //register pointer pointing to first register (seconds)
TransmitOneByte(0x13); //seconds register value
StopTransfer(); //I2C Stop

IdleI2C2(); //I2C wait

while(1)
{
    RTC_read();

    putsUART1(value2);
    putsUART1(value1);
    putsUART1("\n");
    DelayMs(1000);
}

}

//RTC_read function:

void RTC_read()
{
StartTransfer(FALSE); //I2C Start
TransmitOneByte(0xD0); //I2C slave address
TransmitOneByte(0x00); //Register address
StopTransfer(); //I2C Stop

IdleI2C2(); //i2C Stop

StartTransfer(TRUE);    //I2C Restart
TransmitOneByte(0xD1);  //Slave address to read

//Reading from I2C slave
if(I2CReceiverEnable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS, TRUE) == I2C_RECEIVE_OVERFLOW)
{
  putsUART1("Error: I2C Receive Overflow\n");
}
else
{
   while(!I2CReceivedDataIsAvailable(EEPROM_I2C_BUS));
    sec = I2CGetByte(EEPROM_I2C_BUS); //storing seconds into sec variable
}
StopTransfer(); //I2C Stop

    //converting sec to ASCII
    x1 = sec & 0x0F;
    p1 = x1 | 0x30;
    y1 = sec & 0xF0;
    y1 = y1 >> 4;
    p2 = y1 | 0x30;

    sprintf(value1,"%c",p1);
    sprintf(value2,"%c",p2);
}
```

Comment: In your binary-coded-decimal conversion, you end up with p1 and p2 as ASCII characters in the range 0x30..0x39, print them with `sprintf(value1, "%c", p1);` instead of using the %d format.

Comment: Also note your example prints 51 49 = 0x33 0x31 = "31" instead of "13", the 1's place is in 0x0F and the 10's place is in 0xF0. So put character p2 before p1.

Comment: @MarkU Thanks now I am receiving 13 on terminal. But why it is not updating. It should automatically increment so I should receive 13,14,15... please correct me if I am wrong. I am beginner and ready to learn.!

Comment: @MarkU Do I need to include my read function inside while(1) so that it reads every time and then displays it on UART. I have tried doing this but I am receiving some random ASCII char

Comment: [DS1307 datasheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1307.pdf) table 2 shows register 0 bit 7 CH "clock halt", normally 1 (disabled) when power first applied. But your example seems to indicate that bit is 0 (otherwise your first BCD digit would be outside the 0-9 range). But the DS1307 requires an external 32kHz clock, maybe that external clock isn't running? If you have an oscilloscope, can you write register 7 (Control) with SQWE=1 (enabling the buffered output pin SQW/OUT) and verify whether the clock is running?

Comment: As a diagnostic you could try looping the read forever inside while(1) {}. Or you could use something like getch() to pause, until you send any character, and use that to delay between readings.

Comment: Are you using one of the preassembled DS1307 boards that includes a battery holder and the 32kHz crystal, or did you build your own using a DS1307 IC?

Comment: I am using the preassembled DS1307 boards. It has battery and 32khz crystal. I have included the complete read function inside while(1) and the seconds register is getting updated. But when I put value into the minute register, it also starts updating every sec which should not happen. I am updating my question with complete code.

Comment: @MarkU I am able to read each register(sec,min,hr) individually but not together. According to datasheet, master need to give `ACK` after every read and `NACK` at the end. I am giving `AckI2C2();` after reading sec and min value and `NotAckI2C2();` after reading hour value but then it doesnt display anything

Comment: Use an oscilloscope to capture the I2C waveforms, and compare to datasheet. I know I2C but not the PIC's library functions, so I can't help you debug any further. [Search the PIC I2C questions](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pic+i2c?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and if none of those help, post a new question tagged for [tag:pic] and [tag:i2c], including your scope shots of the generated I2C waveforms, and trimmed source code [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . I suggest you move the binary-coded-decimal code into a separate function. Cheers--

Answer (score 1):

The `51` `49`makes perfect sense. They are the ASCII codes for `3` and `1`, resp. Why the reverse order? You started by selecting the low order nibble, instead of the high order nibble.

**How to send the character instead of its ASCII code?**
Use "%c" as format string instead of "%d" (which formats a decimal number).